# how to fit a long text into a UITextView or UILabel

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i'm developing an ios app with xamarin.
i need to fit a long text into a content (UILabel or UITextView).
this is the code i used:

```
var descStrLabel = new UITextView(new CGRect(0, 250, w, 550));
        descStrLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
        descStrLabel.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(10.0f);
        descStrLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        descStrLabel.TextColor = UIColor.LightGray;
        descStrLabel.Text = @"HERE THE LONG TEXT...";
        //descStrLabel.Lines = 0;
        descStrLabel.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
        View.Add(unified);
        View.Add(subtitle);
        View.Add(descStrLabel);
```

When i debug the application, the last part of the text is missing...

maybe i need to set the width at runtime...

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You might need to extend the width of the frame.

Comment: For example? I'm new of xamarin and ios apps..

Comment: Whatever your w variable value is, increase it until you see all of the text. Should fix it. I'd also suggest using UILabel instead of UITextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know how you want to "fit" the text. If you want to show the text all in one line, try calling `SizeToFit()`:

```
desc.SizeToFit();
```

documentation for `SizeToFit()`:

> Moves and resizes the UIView so that it tightly encloses its UIView.Subviews

If you want the `UITextView` to wrap lines, then you don't need to do anything! Line wrapping is enabled by default. If it doesn't for you, try setting `LineBreakMode`:

```
desc.TextContainer.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
```

documentation for `WordWrap`:

> Wraps at the first word that does not fit.